# bibliography not compiling correctly

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

For some reason only one of my bibliography references is compiling properly. The others are not appearing in the reference list at all and do not appear correctly when I type '\cite{source}'. I have one book source (compiling correctly) and the rest are article sources (none compiling correctly). I have looked extensively at the documentation for the article in bibtex but I cannot see that I am missing anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{My dissertation}
\author{My name}
\date{May 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{ostrovskii}


\cite{frankl}

\cite{erdos} 

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

%% Below is the reference list page (sample) entitled ref.bib

```
@BOOK{ostrovskii,
        AUTHOR = "
Ostrovskii, Mikhail",
        TITLE = "
Metric Eembeddings : Bilipschitz and coarse embeddings into Banach Spaces",
        PUBLISHER = {Berlin: De Gruyter},
        YEAR = 2013}
        
        
@article{frankl,
    AUTHOR =       "Frankl, N., Kupavskii, A., Swanepoel, K. ",
    TITLE =        "Embedding graphs in Euclidean space",
    JOURNAL =      "Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A",
    YEAR =         2020,
    VOLUME =       "171",
    DOI =          "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2019.105146"
}
        
@article{erdos,
    author =       "Erdős, P.; Harary, F.; Tutte, W. T. ",
    title =        "On the dimension of a graph",
    journal =      "Mathematika",
    year =         1965,
    volume =       "12",
    number = "2",
    pages = "118-122",
    DOI =          " doi:10.1112/s0025579300005222"
}
```

Comment: Replace the commas and semicolons between authors with `and`. For example: `Frankl, N. and Kupavskii, A. and Swanepoel, K.` or simpler: `N. Frankl and A. Kupavskii and K. Swanepoel`

Comment: @Ivan This worked thank you! If you copy and paste that as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Thank you, but my advice is quite basic and not worthy of a real answer.